# GData Spreadsheet and GSX Namespaces

Tags: c#, linq, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I'm trying to read Google Spreadsheet programatically. Unfortunately, I can't use GData libraries because the platform is Windows Phone.

After reading the content of the spreadsheet using the list API, I get indidual rows as XElements of form

```
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0At7MazQVk6r1dHNOLS02MmVONDdLSDRNSjVPcUZRb0E/1/private/values/chk2m</id>
  <updated>2011-04-16T06:23:48.922Z</updated>
  <category scheme="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006" term="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006#list" />
  <title type="text">0002</title>
  <content type="text">ssname: Some random address, latitude: 2.8595084738555, longtitude: 167.0312830513769, fuel: x, maintenance_2: x</content>
  <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0At7MazQVk6r1dHNOLS02MmVONDdLSDRNSjVPcUZRb0E/1/private/values/chk2m" />
  <gsx:stationid xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">PK0002</gsx:stationid>
  <gsx:ssname xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">Svs Stn</gsx:ssname>
  <gsx:address xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">Some random address</gsx:address>
  <gsx:tel xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">12345678</gsx:tel>
  <gsx:latitude xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">1.35</gsx:latitude>
  <gsx:longtitude xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">103.80312830513769</gsx:longtitude>
  <gsx:operatinghours xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"></gsx:operatinghours>
  <gsx:fuel xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">x</gsx:fuel>
  <gsx:fuel_2 xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"></gsx:fuel_2>
  <gsx:maintenance xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"></gsx:maintenance>
  <gsx:maintenance_2 xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended">x</gsx:maintenance_2>
  <gsx:amenities xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"></gsx:amenities>
  <gsx:amenities_2 xmlns:gsx="http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended"></gsx:amenities_2>
</entry>
```

I'm interested only in elements starting with  namespace. So I declared the namespace like this and check every descendant if it matches it.

```
XNamespace gsx = "http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006/extended";
            IEnumerable<XElement> allItems = xe.Descendants();
            foreach (XElement xItem in allItems)
            {
                if (xItem.Name.NamespaceName == gsx.NamespaceName)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("$$$" + xItem);
                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("XXX" + xItem);
                }
            }
```

I'm sure there is an elegant way by specifying this filter as an XName parameter to xe.Descendants() method. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

`xe.Elements().Where(el => el.Name.Namespace == gsx)` should give you all child elements of `xe` which are in the `gsx` namespace you have defined. So that is what is possible, instead of putting an if statement into the foreach loop you can simply filter the Elements (or Descendants if needed) with a Where method call.